# Error with Compiling Qt 5.0

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, qt5

If I want to Build and run my application in Qt 5.0, nothing happens. I do not get any errors or something. Just nothing.

Some more information:
I have Windows 7 64-bit
Qt Creator 2.8 (Based on Qt 5.0)
I'm using a MSVC compiler

Here are some screenshot:
[image]
This is my current kit.
[image]

These are my compilers:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using any other compilers, like MinGW?

Comment: That red ! means something. What does it say if you hover over that?

Comment: If you go onto the QT downloads page and download "Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 689 MB)" it should have all the compilers already built in and is ready to use straight away.

Comment: @otisonoza 'the compiler cannot produce code for this Qt Version', So I need a other compiler I guess

Comment: @tomstock Can you provide a link or something for MinGW?

Comment: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline.exe

Comment: Just google MinGW download and pick the one that meets your system requirements. However you will still need to add the compiler to QT which can be difficult. It's far easier to uninstall your current version of QT and re-download it with MinGW already connected up. 

Try http://qt-project.org/downloads and download  "Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 689 MB)" and you should be ready to go!

Comment: The kit include _MSVC2010_ in it's name, so Visual studio 2010 is needed (if you didn't renamed the kit), and you seem to have Visual studio 2012 it that correct? Anyway you need to install the correct Qt binaries for the C++ compiler you want to use, so check what Visual Studio do you have and install the corresponding Qt libraries or as other already said go with the MinGW version that one installs MinGW compiler too (when you install it make sure you check MinGW to be installed too)

Comment: Can you show us the "Project" page? (On the left.)

Comment: I've installed Qt again with MinGW included. And got rid of the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You downloaded a MSVC2010 (i.e. MSVC 10) package of Qt and are trying to use it with MSVC2013 (i.e. MSVC 12, as detected by Qt).

That's of course not possible, you need a Qt build matching your compiler.

(If "of course" seems like an overstatement to you, ask Microsoft to keep binary compatibility across its compiler versions.)